# Should we have a new game tag for Victoria 3

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation

It seems as of now we do not have a tag for the newly released game Victoria 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags can't be created ahead of time.  We simply need to wait for a question for the game to occur.  If/once that happens, the asker can tag the question with [victoria-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/victoria-3), which will in turn create the tag.